# how can i code in pygame and move image selectivelly?

Tags: python, pygame

i'm making a game by using pygame, and also tring to learn this. but i'm facing a little hickup.
how do i selectively move an image in pygame ?
i let the display be 800x600 and the point is all start at y 511
x at 62, 124. size of the image is 21x21

```
Tower1 = pygame.image.load('assets/Tower1.png')
Tower2 = pygame.image.load('assets/Tower2.png')
```

if i hit a box it will move the image in the box along with the mouse, and other
image doesn't move

form [Pygame drag background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812873/pygame-drag-background-image)

i can get moving image, but i can't make it move one by one.

```
while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #gameExit = True
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            #event.buttons returns (0,0,0) <=> (left, mid, right)
            print (event)
            if event.buttons[LeftButton]:
                rel = event.rel
                pos = event.pos
                #print (rel)
                #print (pos)
                if (rangeHitPoint(62,511,(21,21),pos)):
                    #moveImage()





            if event.buttons[RightButton]:
                pass


def rangeHitPoint(x,y,imgeSize,Musepos):
    (w,h) = imgeSize
    (musex, mousey) = Musepos
    if x < musex and y < mousey:
        if (x+w) > musex and (y+h) > mousey:
            return True
    else:
        return False

def moveImage(image,pos):
    imgPos = pygame.Rect(pos, (0, 0))
    LeftButton = 0
    gameExit = False
    while not gameExit:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                #gameExit = True
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if e.buttons[LeftButton]:
                    # clicked and moving
                    rel = e.rel
                    imgPos.x += rel[0]
                    imgPos.y += rel[1]
        gameDisplay.blit(image, imgPos)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.delay(60)
        gameExit = True


def displayImage(image,x,y):        
    gameDisplay.blit(image,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Why did you replace the code that moves the image with `#moveImage`, you are asking very specifically about moving the image.

Comment: @imallett i didn't write on it because i think it might be a bit long..

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen because i think my code looks too shity...

Comment: let me know what you guys want in order to solve, i will add to the question if i know.

Comment: @imallett since you commented, i assume you will going to help.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen since you commented, i assume you will going to help.

Comment: why does moveImage have its own event loop? Is it possible it should be replaced with something like `gameDisplay.blit(image, pygame.Rect(e.pos, e.rel))` and sorry I am having trouble getting pygame working on my computer since an update so I won't be able to test your code, sorry.

Comment: @Stv We have no obligation to help you. In spite of myself, here's a hint: (1) reread my comment (2) read your own question as if you were someone else. The point is, I'm still not even sure what problem you're trying to solve. Furthermore, you yourself linked to a question that _already shows_ (with very excellent code, BTW) how to draw and move an image (probably relevant). Your code appears to be a broken copy of it. Without context, I can't know what you're trying to do to it. Short answer: understand that code, then troubleshoot problems you have with it in _focused, clear_ questions.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen i just install this on a ubantu vm and installed pygame using this http://pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensenand btw i know i shouldn't have two loop but right now i don't know what i should do. so ....

Comment: @imallett i think i given enough information, and please read the title. All i want to do is in a window, draw two image using blit(image), then move them selectively. The link i give only move one image, and it will move the image even the mouse is not on the image. let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Stv is clearly new to this site with 6 rep, there is no need to be so harsh.

Comment: @Stv, I'm not sure what rel is, I tried printing out event.rel in my own pygame and got an error. Anyways, try keeping it simple for your first moving image. Rather than trying to explain it here, I will refer you to some sources that should help you out. First, a couple of the docs. http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/MoveIt.html http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html And now a similar question from stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947389/how-to-continuously-move-an-image-in-pygame

Comment: @DavidJayBrady you got the first part right, but everyone seems to be very mean on this site

Answer (score 0):

by adding a boolean in the while loop, and set that when the range is clicked this boolean = true, then outside that if. set another if boolean: moveImage().
make sure let this equal False again.
how easy this is ....